# How to display an image from AttachedPicture | Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, id3

I'm trying to display a cover image from an MP3 file. I'm getting the ID3 tags from https://github.com/NiKoTron/dart-tags.

My Code:

```
TagProcessor tp = TagProcessor();
tp.getTagsFromByteArray(bytes).then((l) async {

  AttachedPicture picture = l[1].tags['picture']['Cover (front)'];

  log(picture.toString()); // ->[log] {mime:image/png, description:, bitmap: iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABLAAAASw...}
});
```

The `mime: image/png` is just a string, so I don't exactly know how to get the image.

Comment: You're getting the bitmap of the image. Did you try displaying the bitmap? I think [Image.memory](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.memory.html) displays images from a bitmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`AttachedPicture`](https://pub.dev/documentation/dart_tags/latest/dart_tags/AttachedPicture/AttachedPicture.html) has property `imageData` which is of type `List<int>`.

You could use `Image.memory` to display `imageData` by using [`Uint8List.fromList`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-typed_data/Uint8List/Uint8List.fromList.html).

```dart
import 'dart:typed_data';

Image.memory(
  Uint8List.fromList(imageData),
);
```